# How can I set a variable in the body of a node?

Tags: 7, theming

In Drupal 7 I've created a node of type basic page.
Then in Body field I've inserted some markup mixed with php code.
Then this was saved in PHP text format.
In the above mentioned markup I have variable I'd like to output to html.
I tried some preprocess functions but that didn't give me any result.
How can I set the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [What is best method for token replacement within node content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/what-is-best-method-for-token-replacement-within-node-content)

If you are feeling lack of available tokens, you can extend it with tokens hooks.